# Meteor - Accounts UI Template Get Reverts to Original Upon CSS Save

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using the `accounts-ui` package and I have edited:
 `Meteor._def_template("_loginButtonsLoggedOutSingleLoginButton"`

but every time I save my CSS this file regenerates and is overridden. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

This is the hot code file editing feature. When you edit a file i think (not sure) meteor copies over the raw meteor files back into your project.

To get passed this you need to copy `accounts-ui` into a a directory called `/packages` in your project to override the default meteor package.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  The templates were not overriding the ones in the meteor static cache / packages folder.